# Spring Boot 2.5.12 : Causes error - Could not initialize Logback logging from classpath:logback-spring.xml

Tags: spring-boot, log4j, logback

I have recently upgraded the springboot 2.5.12. Now getting the error is like this

> Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'null'
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize Logback logging
> from classpath:logback-spring.xml     at
> org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:168)
>
> Caused by: ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException: Parser
> configuration error occurred  at
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder.buildSaxParser(SaxEventRecorder.java:89)
> Caused by: ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException: Parser
> configuration error occurred
>
> at
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder.recordEvents(SaxEventRecorder.java:57)
> at
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:151)
> at
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:110)
> at
> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:53)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.configureByResourceUrl(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:188)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:165)
> ... 38 more Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException:
> unrecognized feature
> http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities     at
> org.gjt.xpp.sax2.Driver.setFeature(Driver.java:178) Caused by:
> org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: unrecognized feature
> http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities
>
> at
> org.gjt.xpp.jaxp11.SAXParserImpl.setFeatures(SAXParserImpl.java:149)

Other dependencies are

> org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.30 ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.6

> ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.6

> net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:4.5.1

> org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.16.0

Thanks for any help

logback-spring.xml

> &grt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>
> ```
> <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
>
> <property scope="context" name="AppName" value="my-api" />
> <property scope="context" name="Comp" value="task" />
> <property scope="context" name="SchemaLocation" value="/pcfSchema.avsc" />
> <property scope="context" name="index" value="task-apis" />
>
> <contextName>my-api</contextName>
>
> <appender name="ACTION_STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
>     <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
>         <layout class="com.ORG.util.PcfFormatter">
>         </layout>
>     </encoder>
> </appender>
>
> <springProfile name="local">
>     <property scope="context" name="ENV" value="Dev" />
>     <logger name="com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
>         <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
>     </logger>
>     <logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN" additivity="false">
>         <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
>     </logger>
>     <logger name="org.dozer" level="WARN" additivity="false">
>         <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
>     </logger>
> </springProfile>
>
> <springProfile name="development">
>     <property scope="context" name="ENV" value="Dev" />
>     <logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN" additivity="false">
>         <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
>     </logger>
>     <logger name="org.dozer" level="WARN" additivity="false">
>         <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
>     </logger>
> </springProfile>
>
> <springProfile name="production">
>     <property scope="context" name="ENV" value="Prod" />
>     <logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN" additivity="false">
>         <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
>     </logger>
>     <logger name="org.dozer" level="WARN" additivity="false">
>         <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
>     </logger>
> </springProfile>
>
> <root level="WARN">
>     <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
> </root> </configuration>
> ```

Comment: please provide your log configuration. such as logback-spring.xml

Comment: i cant identify  the class of PcfFormatter. and root logger use the appender called STDOUT,but the config file not exist.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I add the org.codehaus.janino:janino dependency follow the link
https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#aot-build-setup-configuration
It worked for me!

[image]

Comment: The image or page are not available.

Comment: You can simply add org.codehaus.janino:janino denpendency to pom file and rebuild the project. The version of page is udpated frequency